# Heroku Logs -TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku

```
npm v6.12.0
node v10.16.0
```

I'm using the firebase sdk for my app. I never had this problem before until I changed all my server info today. This is the Heroku error logs I get when I try to access the code remotely via my app

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

I run `$ heroku logs --app myAppName`:

```
2019-10-21T21:07:12.988431+00:00 app[web.1]: privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
2019-10-21T21:07:12.988433+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-10-21T21:07:12.988435+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-21T21:07:12.988436+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

But when I run `node app.js` or locally from terminal everything works fine. Also when I run `npm start` from terminal everything works fine. What could be the cause of this issue?

Here is the code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: process.env.MY_CUSTOM_TOKEN
  }
});
```

And inside my `.env` file which I added to `.gitignore`

```
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I also tried:

```
// removed the .replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY
```

and in the .env file:

```
// I added quotes
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

**What does Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined mean?** It can't be the value of the FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY because when I run `node app.js` or `npm start` I would get errors which I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been workin on this for hours. I tried all sorts of things but eventually I just deleted the entire folder that contained all of the code and deleted the app from Heroku, after I redid everything from scratch it works now (I did this more then 10 times since yesterday).

I read that sometimes Heroku's servers are down and maybe that with the fact that I'm on a free tier caused some sort of internal lag. Whatever the reason it oddly works now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you run locally (on `firebase serve`) that the environment variables are set automatically by Firebase. On Heroku, this is not the case. You could load them through the `.env` file, but a better way would be to use Heroku's config vars.

You can set the config vars (for `FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY`, `FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID`, etc) from the Heroku Dashboard:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. I actually did that and the same error keeps appearing. It’s very odd.

Comment: @AnyPhitlok what does cannot read property replace of undefined mean?

Comment: It means that `process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY` has the value `undefined` so the function `replace()` cannot be called. The reason it is undefined is that there  is no property `FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY` on `process.env`.